# Almacenar datos obtenidos con axios de manera local para manipularlos

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una consulta a traves de Axios, consigo obtener los datos pero estos datos necesito modificarlos ya que al ejecutarse un evento debo actualizar la informacion, pero cada que ejecuto el evento la data vuelve a cargarse como evito esto y almaceno de manera local la inforamcion para poder modificarla.

```
//obtener datos del api
const obtenerDatos = async (url)=>{    
    try {
        let allData = await axios(url);
        let datos = await allData.data;
        let lineas = datos.split(/\n/).splice(9);
        let columData = new Array();
        let count_location = new Array();         
        lineas.forEach(element => {  
            columData.push(element.split("|"));         
        });
        let locations = new Array();

        //obtener solo los valores de la columna 8
        columData.forEach(fila => {
            if(!locations.includes(fila[8],0)){
                locations.push(fila[8]);
            }                 
        });
        //contar la cantidad de veces que se repite el valor de la columna 8 en el array
        locations.forEach(location => {            
            let cantidad = 0;    
            columData.forEach(linea => {                
                if(location === linea[8]){    
                    cantidad += 1; 
                }    
            });    
            let obj = {
                location: location,
                espacios: 12 - cantidad
            }
            count_location.push(obj);
            count_location.sort();
        });    
        return count_location;            
    } catch (error) {            
        console.log(error);    
    }
}
```

la información obtenida con axios la convierto en un array de objetos los cuales tienen la propiedad espacios, cada vez que se ejecuta el evento esta propiedad del objeto debe disminuir hasta convertirse en 0 y pasar al siguiente objeto que tenga un valor mayor a 0.

```
boton.addEventListener('click', async (event)=>{
    const getdata = async ()=>{
        let campos = document.querySelectorAll('.loc');
        const data = await obtenerDatos(url);
        for(let x = 1; x <= campos.length - 1; x++) {            
            let sel = document.querySelector(`.lc${x}`)
            sel.disabled = false;
            // let qty = campos.length;    
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                const element = await data[i];                
                if(element.espacios > 0){                    
                    sel.value = await element.location;
                    element.espacios --;                        
                break                        
                }        
            };
            sel.disabled = true
        };    
    };

    await getdata();        
    saveDynamicDataToFile();
})
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu código. No sé en qué momento se vuelve a ejecutar tu llamada axios para cargar la data. Aunque puedes almacenar tus datos en [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hay una función obtenerDatos, con la que a través de axios obtengo la información, la filtro y almaceno en un array. cuando el evento se ejecuta llama a la función y almacena el array en otra variable, utiliza la información del array para obtener un listado de localizaciones disponibles las cuales deben disminuir hasta llegar a 0 pero por cada vez que se ejecuta el evento la información es cargada de nuevo y las ubicaciones vuelven a estar disponibles. Espero me entiendan